# What is the difference between jquery-ui.css and jquery-ui.css?s2j=3.3.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2-jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cache busting via params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692665/cache-busting-via-params)

I'm using `struts2jquery` plugin and I wanna change a property inside `jquery-ui.css` which is inside a jar file called `struts2jquery-plugin-3.3.1.jar`.

The problem is after I changed that property I can see the value changed in the file but the browser still using the original value. When I debug the problem I figured out the browser is using a file `jquery-ui.css?s2j=3.3.1` and once I remove the `?s2j=3.3.1` the browser reads the file I have changed and got the new value!

So, any one please can help me out to understand what is the difference between `jquery-ui.css` and `jquery-ui.css?s2j=3.3.1` and how to change the value in `jquery-ui.css?s2j=3.3.1` bcz I don't know where this file is.

Comment: You'll often see this "cache-busting" technique used with underscore as the querystring key, and the current Date (in milliseconds) as the querystring value, like: `someFile.js?_=29430423420342`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the browser cache. When you append a querystring like `?s2j=3.3.1` to the URL, the browser considers it a new asset, still uncached, and fetches a fresh copy from the server.

It's common to see this technique being used to avoid caching on ajax requests. jQuery, for example, appends a timestamp to the URL every time you call its `$.ajax` function with the `cache` option set to `false`.

Comment: Thanks bfavaretto. You are right I just empty the browser's cache and get it works like charm.