# Version control of css and javascript files using apache

Tags: javascript, css, apache, version-control

Whenever I update my website to include new features, I obviously need to modify the existing css and js files. As the browsers cache the css and js files the site looks bad. Can I append some value at the end of each css and js files using .htaccess files so that the browsers are forced to reload these files each time my website gets updated.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/update-on-css-caching/

Comment: This is why i loove the grails-resources plugin...

Comment: Please consider trying one of the approaches listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692665/cache-busting-via-params