# passing any random query to webpage makes it behave differently

Tags: php

I am trying to learn PHP and stumbled across a webpage that does not make sense ...
The following web page acts differently if you pass any random query to it:

http://www.trumpcasinos.com/hi-res-gallery-en.html

If you look at the page above it will not display all of the stuff ...

if you change the URL to something like:

http://www.trumpcasinos.com/hi-res-gallery-en.html?anyrandomcharactershere

The page looks different (it seems that there is more information .. without the query it just cuts off) ... this is confusing me ...

anyone know why this happens? and how to fix it?

Comment: @Brad how do i revert?

Comment: I took care of it for you.  But all you have to do is click the "edited x minutes ago" link and go back to your version.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692665/cache-busting-via-params)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have caught this page in the middle of updating their code, but the cached content has not cleared yet.

If you go to that URL without any querystring, you will note that the response time is extremely fast.  If you go to the URL with a querystring, it is no longer cached and the server takes several seconds to get a response to you.  Additional evidence for this is that some of the caching headers are different as well.

Comment: if i show you the source code in private, will you be able to help me?

Comment: @Moose, Is this your site?  If so, just flush your server caches.  If this isn't your site, I doubt you are having the same trouble, unless you are looking at `$_GET`.  In any case, you should post a snippet of code on Stack Overflow that reproduces your problem.  Otherwise, you can hire me or someone else to fix it for you, but I'm booked up at the moment.