# Forcing browser to refresh files everyday

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I want to force the browser to not cache files for my react based web app for more than a day. How do I do that?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control

Comment: Is there a way to set the cache-control header in s3 or cloudfront?

Comment: Try reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18774069/amazon-cloudfront-cache-control-no-cache-header-has-no-effect-after-24-hours

Comment: I think your first comment will work. (Found a way to add cache-control header from s3). For reference you can go to object -> Properties -> Metadata -> Add Metadata -> Select Cache-Control and put value as (public, max-age=86400)

Comment: As mentioned in your second link, this is not for cloudfront to not cache it for more than a day. This is for the browser referencing older files. I already dealt with cloudfront caching issue with invalidation feature in cloudfront.

Answer (score 0):

Type in the address bar

```
about:config
```

then press the button

```
I accept the risk
```

then type in the bar

```
browser.cache.disk.enable
```

then double click on it, to make it false

exit firefox and restart-it.

do the same with

```
browser.cache.memory.enable
```

and set to 1 the pref

```
browser.cache.check_doc_frequency
```

if you want to read more:

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.cache.disk.enable

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.cache.memory.enable