# What is the purpose of adding a version in CSS?

Tags: html, css, gridless-boilerplate

I´m using Gridless Boilerplate and this is how the main.css file is called in the header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css?version=1" />
```

I'd like to know what the purpose of adding "?version1" is.

Answer (score 7):

It's used to avoid caching issues. When you edit your css file you'll increment that version number and the browser will (presumably) fetch a new copy rather than using its cached version.

See [Cache-Busting via params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692665/cache-busting-via-params).

Answer (score 3):

If that file changes over time, by appending that query string you force browsers that normally cache that file to get a fresh copy.