# Laravel don't update DB model through XMLHttpRequest + Timeout

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel-4, eloquent, settimeout

For a few hours I am stuck on this problem.

I have a url

```
increase/1
```

and route

```
Route::get('increase/{id}', '***Controller@action***');
```

and controller

```
public function action***($id) {
    $model = ***::where***->first();
    $model->counter += 1;
    $model->save();
}
```

When I hit url in browser, **counter is incremented -> DB updated.**

---

When my template is rendered and I want to call this url through XMLHttpRequest. I have a script on the bottom of page (xhr.timeout is not important).

```
<script>
function pageViewIncrease() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "{{ url() }}/increase/{{ id }}", true);
    xhr.timeout = 0;
    xhr.send(null);
}
    pageViewIncrease();
</script>
```

When template is rendered, **counter is incremented -> DB updated.**

---

But I want to call this "script" with delay.

```
setTimeout( pageViewIncrease, 290 );
```

With timeout, counter is **sometimes incremented** and **sometimes not**.

With bigger timeout (500,1000,...), Laravel **not update model anymore**.

I really don't know what am I doing wrong :(.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using a real controller name instead of ***Controller? Or are you just using that as an example?

Comment: Just an example. But as I said. The problem is setTimeout function. Without setTimeout, script is working fine. It looks something like Laravel don't want to update model when I am not calling the route immediately after page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I solved it.**

I found out "delayed request content" is from cache.

[image]

Then I edit my code with help from "[Problems with cached result when sending a XMLHttpRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695843/problems-with-cached-result-when-sending-a-xmlhttprequest)".

```
xhr.open("GET", "{{ url() }}/increase/{{ id }}?t=" + Math.random(), true);
```

and my code is working even with

```
setTimeout( pageViewIncrease, 3000 );
```