# How to use css versioning

Tags: css

Actually i think this is css versioning techniques.May be I am wrong,Anyway I want to learn it,

In google font they used something like this:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans);
```

In another website they used:

`href='http://www.example.com/css?v=1243'`

How can we implements this type of things with our css?

Comment: The 2nd example looks like [cache breaking/busting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692665/cache-busting-via-params), not versioning.

Comment: Also, I suspect the first one is code that sends out a different CSS depending on the parameter passed in. In other words, it's not possible with pure CSS.

Comment: @user2864740 Any running examples on  cache breaking/busting ?

Comment: @Jimmer The answers in the link I added to my comment should contain a relevant explanation. The breaking/busting is due to the change in the query parameter making it a "different resource" than the CSS data that might have been already downloaded and cached. The "version" number can either be updated manually or (and especially in the case of dynamically-generated HMTL) using automated tooling.