# mod_rewrite - rewrite directory to query string except /#!/

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite www.domain.com/something/some/ to 
www.domain.com/index.php?q=something/some/

This is what I have so far:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ([a-z-]+)/?$
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But I want to exclude urls like these:
www.domain.com/#!/something

Could you please help?

Thanks,
John

Comment: The `#` and everything after that shouldn't ever reach your server, as it's a fragment identifier, which is not supposed to be attached to a request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Use of `.+` also takes care of `/#!/something` since Apache will only get `/` for that as text after `#` doesn't reach web server.