# Internet Explorer HTML Video Overwrite File

Tags: html, internet-explorer, video

I would like to start off by first saying that I am not a web developer so I apologize if I explain thing poorly.

I am working on a simple in house digital signage solution. We create the show in power point, then save it as a video. We then loop that video on a webpage.

```
<video autoplay loop muted id="video-bg" preload = "auto" 
style="position: fixed; left: 0; bottom: 0; width: 80%;
height: auto; z-index: -100;">
<source src="./test.mp4"      
type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

This is the code used to play the video, extremely basic but it is all we needed.

To update the show we simply overwrite the existing video and when the page auto refreshes the new video is played. This works when the site is being displayed in Chrome. In IE we can not save the file as we receive an error it is in use.

Using process explorer I see that the file is in use by IE but not Chrome.

Is there a difference in how Chrome and IE use a file?

Thanks in advanced to anyone who can help narrow down this problem.

Comment: I’m going to guess that you are not requesting this via HTTP from a local web server, but that you are accessing this via the local file system only …? In that case, I wouldn’t consider it that much of a surprise that “opening” the file in a browser might block it from being overwritten, same as opening it in any number of other programs that use a blocking file opening mode would.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692665/cache-busting-via-params

Answer (score 0):

I did not research about this topic but probably Chrome is caching your video and playing it from the cache. However you can try to force the cache behavior, take look at: [HTML CACHE](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_app_cache.asp) and see if it works in I.E.

Add the manifest.cache in your html tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html manifest="manifest.cache">
```

And include the manifest.cache file in your folder:

```
CACHE MANIFEST 
/test.mp4
```

I hope that I helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than just opening the webpage into the browser we are using The Uniform Server and hosting the page locally on the computer.

Doing this allows us to overwrite the file regardless of the browser we are using.