# Remove a query string added to Wordpress URLs

Tags: php, wordpress

I have to work with a Wordpress installation that wasn't mine, and I need to work out some things to optimize performance.

Among other things, I've found that almost every single URL, specially for static files, is appended with a query string, and it's always the same:

- https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/gfi-150x42.png**?e1e0dc**
- https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/healthline-150x42.png**?e1e0dc**

And so on.

Does anybody know a plugin that can be causing this? I have the following installed, and i can't find the one causing it or if it's something else:

- Advanced Custom Fields
- Akismet
- Category Post Widget
- Contact Form 7
- Envato WordPress Toolkit
- Forms: 3rd-Party Integration
- Google XML Sitemaps
- LayerSlider WP
- Ready! Backup
- Ready! Backup PRO
- Redirection
- Remove query strings from static resources
- Special Recent Posts FREE Edition
- Twoot ToolKit
- W3 Total Cache
- Wickett Twitter Widget
- WordPress-to-Lead for Salesforce CRM
- WordPress HTTPS
- WordPress SEO
- WP-PageNavi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appending a version number as a URL query string is a [common cache-busting solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9692665/211627).

It looks like W3 Total Cache may be the culprit here. [Their website says](https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/) that one of the features is:

> - Browser caching using cache-control, future expire headers and entity tags (ETag) with "cache-busting"

[According to the author](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-w3-total-cache-remove-query-string-from-static-content) of the plugin, you can disable this feature:

> Uncheck the "Prevent caching of objects after settings change" option on the browser cache settings tab.

Answer (score 4):

You can remove query strings from theme resources (css and javascript files) with this in your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
// Remove Query Strings from enqueue scripts
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', 'remove_query_string' );
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', 'remove_query_string' );
function remove_query_string( $url )
{
    return remove_query_arg( 'ver', $url );
}
```

As for query strings from plugins, I assume that will be a similar fix in each plugin.