# Loading GIF stops animation when submitting a form in Safari

Tags: jquery, forms, animation

Check out this simple [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VpDUG/4952/) (ignore all the javascript code, this question here is only about the animated loading GIF).

I want to show the animated loading GIF before a form gets submitted.

I tried this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
 $('form[name="checkout-form"]').submit();
},1000);
```

And this works fine, the animated loading GIF appears for 1 second, however, it stops the animation as soon as the submit request has been sent.

What do I have to do in order to let the GIF animated until the page loads again (or until the response comes back from the page?)

Comment: I had similar issues with Mobile Safari. The solution was to provide loading indicator as data-uri, base64 background-image. See: https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/ for details.

Answer (score 1):

You need to AJAX the form.
When you submit the form, the page and animations are unloaded.

So try

```
$(function() {
  $('form[name="checkout-form"]').on("submit",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the actual submission
    $("#animationgif").attr("src","submitting.gif?rnd="+new Date().getTime()).show();    
    $.post(this.action,$(this).serialize(),function() {
      $("#animationgif").attr("src","blank.gif").hide();    
    });
  });
});
```

The `?rnd="+new Date().getTime()` is a tactic called [cache busting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692665/cache-busting-via-params), which will make sure it starts from the beginning.
It can be removed if it is a looping ajax throbber.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try... Is this bullet proof in the sense of compatibility to Safari/Firefox/Chrome/IE ?

Comment: I would assume so. You MAY need to add a ?rnd="+new Date().getTime() to make the animation play in IE

Comment: @basZero: did this work for you? I'm finding myself in a similar predicament, and almost all options are/have run out

Comment: @HassanBaig : in my first test it didn't work, to be more concrete, my textarea fields did not serialize correctly (special characters got lost), so this is still open and unanswered for me!