# GIF not working with form submission in Safari but works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gif

I want to run a GIF animation as a loader while a form is being submitted. I have made a very basic form with just a input button which once clicked submits the form and also should get replaced by the GIF.The GIF does not work in Safari but works in Chrome. Client requirement is that the GIF should run in all browsers. Another requirement is that I cannot use AJAX to submit the form as recommended in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32904343/loading-gif-stops-animation-when-submitting-a-form-in-safari?rq=1).

My jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myform").on("submit", function(){
        $(".UploadBtn").hide();
        $("#spinner").show();
        $("#img-spinner").show();
    });
});
```

My CSS;

```
#spinner {
    display: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: serif;
    color: #00C853;
         }

#img-spinner {
    display: none;
             }

.UploadBtn {
    display: show;
           }
```

My HTML;

```
<form id ="myform" action="{% url 'loading_test' %}" method="POST">
<input type="submit" class="UploadBtn">
</form>
<div id="spinner"><img id="img-spinner" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/pacman_orange.gif"> loading</div>
```

Comment: Have you solved the issue? I am facing the same situation.

Comment: Unfortunately no :( I ended up letting go of the problem as making it work on the Safari became a good to have in grand scheme of things.

Comment: I'm still getting this in 2022, iOS 15.

Answer (score 1):

Try specify the width:100px; and height:100px of the image. Its working for me.