# Old browser data still displayed after deployment on tomcat

Tags: javascript, tomcat, browser, web-deployment, browser-cache

Whenever I redeploy my application on tomcat, users on my website still see old content from before deployment including resources like css, js code.

When I remove my browser data, everything is shown correctly.

Is there a way how I can achieve that everybody gets the new content on my website after (tomcat WAR) update on the server without deleting browser data manually?

Comment: Who you gonna call? [Cache busters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692665/cache-busting-via-params).

Comment: don't understand what you mean?

Comment: Sorry, didn't recognize the link the first time