# Font version i CSS3 document

Tags: css, font-face, webfonts

I was looking for answers but I can not find anywhere.
Why are placed version of the font in a CSS file?
It is regulated by a specification?

Below is an example (example comes from: https://github.com/FontFaceKit/open-sans):

```
/* BEGIN Light */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  src: url("./fonts/Light/OpenSans-Light.eot?v=1.1.0");
  src: url("./fonts/Light/OpenSans-Light.eot?#iefix&v=1.1.0") format("embedded-opentype"), url("./fonts/Light/OpenSans-Light.woff2?v=1.1.0") format("woff2"), url("./fonts/Light/OpenSans-Light.woff?v=1.1.0") format("woff"), url("./fonts/Light/OpenSans-Light.ttf?v=1.1.0") format("truetype"), url("./fonts/Light/OpenSans-Light.svg?v=1.1.0#Light") format("svg");
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal; }
/* END Light */
```

Comment: [Here's the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts-3/#font-face-rule). I don't see anything about a version. It's probably something about [cache-busting](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9692665/215552)

Comment: He fooled me the letter "V" - I thought this is version.
Thanks for the explanation Mike.