# Footer changes position on mobile. Depending on http/https (herokuapp)

Tags: html, css, heroku

I use this kind of footer and it works okay on localhost, but how can i fix it on heroku server?

```
html {
position: relative;
min-height: 100%;
}

body{
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.footer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #222;
}
```

[footer with https](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdHcv.png) and [footer with http](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIsJj.png)

Or maybe you can give me a piece of advice, how to create footer that wil be always at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Can you post how you include the css file in the html?

Comment: I use flask so <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: Can you post how that renders in http and https ? I trying to check if you are including it via https in http or vice-versa. Also try opening the https and http versions of the css file in the browser to see if it loads as expected

Comment: there are two link to see the render

Comment: Check the console to see if all resources are being loaded correctly. I wouldn't be surprised if something is not being loaded because of a security reason.

Comment: @KirillLosev it works the same for me from both https and http, might be a cache issue.

Comment: It works nice when I act like phone in google chrom dev tools, but not on my phone.

Comment: @KirillLosev i tested with my phone (*android*)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli finple.herokuapp.com did you test this page or only code in the question?

Comment: I open css on my phone and it hasn't the part? that I need. How can I force browser to load same css everytime?

Comment: @KirillLosev then it is caching.. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692665/cache-busting-via-params

Comment: SOLVED just restart browser on smartphone