# How can i force the browser to get new JavaScript (JS) files? using a script tag in the html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am using the Angularjs Framework, and i update my js controllers a lot, and i want to know how i can force the broweser to get the new/updates js files and not pull them up from cache.

If anyone can help me out that will be great thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cache busting via params](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692665/cache-busting-via-params)

Comment: If you want to get an un-cached file append a new random string to the end of the filename after a `?` for example: `http://example.com/js/file.js?12312312313`

Comment: Heh, I wish I asked about this on SO about 2 years ago. We never found out a clean way to do this and did weird things to check version number and ask the user to clear their cache.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get an un-cached file is to append a string of sorts to the end of the file. This could be a version number, timestamp or some random string.

PHP:

```
<?php
echo '<script src="/js/file.js?t=' . time() . '"></script>';
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
    document.head.appendChild(
        document.createElement('script')
    ).src='/js/file.js?t=' + (new Date().getTime());
<script>
```

For an uncached file every time, change the string on every request.

For an uncached file occasionally, use something like a version number, or an md5 version number.