# meaning of hash after font url css

Tags: css, fonts

In css I have the following code:

```
@font-face {
    src: url('/dist/assets/fonts/icomoon.eot?8as5lf');
```

What does the **8as5lf** stand for? When I go to the file location I dont see those characters anywhere.

Comment: It could be a form of cache busting (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/9692665/1220550) or it could be a really simple kind of access code, or a simple usage tracking code. Hard to say more from a distance.

Comment: Looks like it might be a Git SHA short code, so perhaps it points to a specific commit for the font.

Comment: I have the same question. I created a font with [icon-font-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/icon-font-generator) and there are long numbers behind the url.