# How to clear cache in TWebBrowser in Delphi GMLib?

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser, gmlib

I'm using TGMLib. I need to reload file in TGMGroundOverlay. File on disk has changed but name is the same. TWebBrowser in TGMMap probably keep it on cache and I need to clear cache in TWebBrowser. Is any possibly to do that?

Best Regards!
Patryk

Comment: Use a slighty modified URL by appending a query parameter such as file://path.to.file?version=2. This is known as [cache-busting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692665/cache-busting-via-params)

Comment: Jup. While developing, you could even consider just adding a timestamp there, so you'll basically load everything every time.

Comment: That was great idea, but it not works. To make it i will modify GMlib. I will try to do this.

Thanks for fast reply.

Comment: I modified source of GMlib but it not works... :(

Comment: Can you see the url is actually changed in the HTML output?

Comment: Which URL have you been changing? If this was the URL of your map page then it surely didn't work. In order to force reload of Ground Overlay you have to change the URL of ground overlay image which is a part of TGroundOverlay class.

Comment: I change the URL with do: GMGroundOverlay1.Item[Index].Url
and change bbox with do:
GMGroundOverlay1.Item[Index].Bounds.NE.Lat etc.

And this option not works...

When I clear all collection of TGroundOverlay and Add New Item (file) with new Url (name) then it works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem. Answer of cache-busting and GolezTrol was helping.

The best solution is change the filename and change it on URL (add something like index/id)

filename_index.png

Thank you!
Best regards!