# imagekit used with external storage - how to disable some random number (t=xxxxxxx) at the end of the url

Tags: cdn, imagekit

I have linked my serve with imagekit as CDN, fetching imageing from Digitalocean storage space: as per the blog -
[Optimize and resize images in DigitalOcean Spaces in real-time with ImageKit](https://imagekit.io/blog/optimize-resize-images-digitalocean-spaces-real-time-imagekit/) - This all works fine.

Now when I open html page: imagekit seems to be attaching some random number t=xxxxx at the end of the link

```
imagekit-digitaloceanbucket/static/flora_title/Anacardiaceae_Buchanania%20cochinchinensis_1_Title1.JPG?t=1640178053
```

apparent reason is:
[to clear browser cache as per this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57866305/what-does-t-some-number-mean-when-used-at-the-end-of-an-image-url)

This additional tag is preventing adding any url based query parameters to transform image: [link](https://docs.imagekit.io/features/image-transformations)

expected url with transformation = '/demo/medium_cafe_B1iTdD0C.jpg?**tr=w-200,h-200**'

actual url with tranformation = '/demo/medium_cafe_B1iTdD0C.jpg?**t=12345678?tr=w-200,h-200**' (this does not work)

Question is how to remove this tag getting appended to the url

1: look like they also add such tag to images in Media library and [that could be disabled](https://help.imagekit.io/en/articles/2434122-preventing-random-string-from-getting-added-to-uploaded-file-names)

but how to do disable it when imagekit is used with some external storage?

Answer (score 0):

I could figures this out now: this timestamp was getting generated within my code. setting app.config['CDN_TIMESTAMP'] = False, solved this.  [Thanks to this link](https://www.keycdn.com/support/flask-cdn-integration)