# what is the ?ver=n bit of the js file that shows in a page speed analyzer?

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization, minify, pagespeed

I need to increase our site speed. I'm using GTMetrix although I've tried with a few other page speed testers. Here's the issue: one of the top performance hitters says to minify javascript. Fine, I tried out a couple of the best rated wordpress plugins for minification, but I got the same results, so deleted them. 
http://notarealsite.com/wp-content/plugins/dude-services/public/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.js?ver=ee70a4928c9e111d75

Here is what the js file location looks like. There was only one file in the directory (jquery.dataTables.js) So I took it and ran it through a minifier, and replaced the code (after saving a backup). But it still comes up as the top hitter. I want to understand what the "?ver=n" part is at the end. We are not caching (though we should, and will eventually) and there is only the one js file in the directory and it is definitely minified. Where is this coming from?

Comment: Looks like [cache busting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692665/cache-busting-via-params).

Comment: Yes! I think you are right! Thank you! I will mark this answer as correct as soon as I can figure out how.