# How to do cache busting in Rollup.js?

Tags: javascript, browser-cache, rollupjs

In [my project](https://github.com/trovu/trovu-web), I need to do [cache busting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692665/cache-busting-via-params), since after a new deploy, the browser often only reloads the HTML but not the JS & CSS files.

Currently, I am not building the HTML in any way, it just already sits in the public directory.

The simplest approach seems to be to add a timestamp to the JS reference:

```
<script type="module" src="bundle/index.js?ts=20201026-102300"></script>
```

Now, what is the best way to achieve this in a project that already uses [rollup.js](https://rollupjs.org/)?

I have seen [@rollup/plugin-html](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/html), yet I'm puzzled by the example in its documentation, as it takes a JS file as input:

```
 input: 'src/index.js',
```

What JS file should that be?

Instead I expect that need to define

- an input HTML file
- some space for code to set the timestamp variable
- an output HTML file

So what's the best way to do this, be it with [@rollup/plugin-html](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/html) or with another approach?

Answer (score 0):

Came here looking for an answer to this question myself and a few moments later and a bit of regex fiddling, I got it to work.

*Note: this solution edits your HTML file each time you build it. There is no input (template) HTML and output HTML.*

1. Install [rollup-plugin-replace-html-vars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-replace-html-vars)

`npm install rollup-plugin-replace-html-vars --save-dev`

2. Add this piece of config to your `rollup.config.js` file

```
// rollup.config.js
// ...
plugins: [
    replaceHtmlVars({
        files: '**/index.html',
        from: /\.\/\w+\/\w+\.\w+.\w+\?v=\d+/g,
        to: './dist/app.min.js?v=' + Date.now(),
    }),
]
```

3. In your `index.html`, add this reference to the `app.js`:

```
<script type="module" src="./dist/app.min.js?v=1630086943272"></script>
```

4. Run rollup and the reference to app.js in your index.html will have a timestamp of the build time each time you run it.

**Bonus:**

If you don't have a `.min` in your filename, use this regex instead:

```regex
/\.\/\w+\/\w+\.\w+\?v=\d+/g
```

Full disclosure; I'm no regex wizard, just managed to hack this one together. I bet someone here will have a better way of capturing `./dist/app.min.js?v=1630086943272` with a regex but this works for my solution.

Comment: You also need `import replaceHtmlVars from 'rollup-plugin-replace-html-vars';` at the top.

Comment: Yeah I assumed that if someone's working with ES6 and rollup, they know that functions need to be imported..

Answer (score 0):

I went with using file hashes, which means it's only reloaded when there is a new version for that file.
For that, I wrote my own utility:

```js
function escapeStringRegexp(string) {
    if (typeof string !== 'string') {
        throw new TypeError('Expected a string');
    }

    return string
        .replace(/[|\\{}()[\]^$+*?.]/g, '\\$&')
        .replace(/-/g, '\\x2d');
}

function insertHashToFile(options) {
    return {
        writeBundle(outputOptions) {
            const outputDir = outputOptions.dir ? outputOptions.dir : path.dirname(outputOptions.file);
            let indexHtml = fs.readFileSync(options.htmlFile, 'utf8');

            for (const sourceFile of options.sourceFiles) {
                const fb = fs.readFileSync(path.join(outputDir, sourceFile));
                const hash = crypto.createHash('sha1');
                hash.update(fb)
                const hexHash = hash.digest('hex');

                const replacePattern = new RegExp(escapeStringRegexp(sourceFile) + '(:?\\?h=[^"]+)?', 'g');
                indexHtml = indexHtml.replaceAll(replacePattern, `${sourceFile}?h=${hexHash.substring(0, 8)}`);
            }

            fs.writeFileSync(options.htmlFile, indexHtml);
        },
    };
}
```

and then

```js
plugins: [
    production && insertHashToFile({
        sourceFiles: [
            "bundle.js",
            "bundle.css",
        ],
        htmlFile: "public/index.html",
    }),
]
```