# Fill array with random picture from url that gives random picutres

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, random

The randomizer for width and height works, but it only gets first random photo from collection and generates 10 same images of various dimensions.

```
export const photos = Array.from({length:10},()=> 
    (
        {
            'src': 'https://source.unsplash.com/random',
            'width': Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 2,
            'height': Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 2
        }
    )
)
```

What I would want is that it fills the array with 10 different pictures using that same link.

Comment: You aren't changing the `src` in any way.

Comment: But opening that `src` every time changes the picture. Try opening that link several times

Comment: Doesn't seem like a JavaScript problem at all. If you include multiple images with this URL [the service seems to produce the same picture](https://jsbin.com/peberuvega/edit?html,output).

Comment: [Seems like you can append unique query strings to get different images](https://jsbin.com/giherovala/1/edit?html,output)

Comment: Your browser probably caches the first image it receives. like VLAZ said, you can add a query string to act as a [cache buster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692665/cache-busting-via-params), so your browser will have a unique URL to cache separately.

Comment: @VLAZ That solves it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@VLAZ solved it. Appending some query string gets me random images.

```
export const photos = Array.from({length:10},()=> 
    (
        {
            'src': 'https://source.unsplash.com/random?' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1,
            'width': Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 2,
            'height': Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 2
        }
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
const photos = Array.from({length:10},()=> ({'src': `https://picsum.photos/id/${Math.ceil(Math.random()*999)}/${Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 2}/${Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 2}`}))

console.log(photos)
```