# Super reload or cache deletion

Tags: javascript, jquery

Super reload or cache deletion

I've been looking for a way to do it with Google Chrome for months, but I have no idea.

I'm looking for a way to super reload, how can I super reload?

By the way,

`location.reload (true);`
Well, it's not done at all.
(true) has no meaning at all.

`window.location.href = window.location.href;`

`location.reload (); return false;`

Is not done in the same way.

According to some people, the function itself has been abolished, but can anyone explain in an easy-to-understand manner why the following extensions allow super reloading? [Chrome Hard refresh extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hard-refresh/ichmdelihgokllcnibkcpciljnggojkj)

[Chrome Super Reloader extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/super-reloader/jejoofblfhobdhldeneboocjffiejpgj)

What is the reason why extensions can do it, but user scripts and bookmarklets can't?

Just in case, again, I'm looking for a way to do it with Google Chrome.

```
// I want to do it with the "F5" key.
(function() {
  "use strict";
  document.addEventListener ('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 116) {
      window.location.href = window.location.href; // unexploded
      location.reload (true); // unexploded
      // unexploded
      chrome.browsingData.removeCache ({});
      chrome.tabs.reload (arrayOfTabs [0] .id);
      setTimeout (function () {
        location.reload ();
      }, 2000);
    }
  });
})();
```

Supplement:

The difference between reload and super reload is
You can also see the difference on the stackoverflow.com/ site.

When the code is no longer colored, the <kbd>F5</kbd> key alone will not solve it,

Press the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> keys to cancel.

Comment: F12 -> Network Tab -> Disable Cache

Comment: If you just want the page to load without using the cache, you can call the page with a dynamic querystring that is different each time you call it (using a timestamp is best). The server will believe that it is a new page that hasn't been cached before and therefore will load without the cache. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692665/cache-busting-via-params for details.

Comment: @ScottMarcus you are mistaking here `serverside caching` and `browserside caching`. The browser cache does not care if you change a url parameter.

Comment: @MichaelWalter No, I'm not. If the URL is different than any that has already been accessed, the ***browser*** will see it as a new file and download it without using the cache (the browser ***does care***). The resource URL's ***within*** that document would not have changed though, so images and other resources that have static URLs in the file will utilize the cache, but the main file won't.

Comment: @ScottMarcus you are right, my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Browser extensions have special permissions that webpage scripts will ***never*** get. Webpages are not supposed to edit information that they haven't made. Extensions/add ons have that ability since **every** extension is reviewed by a human *and* a robot. Together, they make sure extensions don't do anything malicious. Imagine trying to do that for ***every*** webpage in the world!

However, the server can control what is and isn't cached using headers. [Here's a list of different servers' header-setting methods](http://cristian.sulea.net/blog/disable-browser-caching-with-meta-html-tags/)

You can set `cache-control` headers in HTML, too. You can do something like `<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />` in the head.

Javascript can [control cache for files it fetches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Comment: Should I do this when inserting with Javascript?

```
window.addEventListener('load', e => {
document.getElementsByTagName('head')
.insertAdjacentHTML
('beforeend',`
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
`);
});
```

Comment: Well, you can just add that tag into the `head` with pure HTML, no JS required. It will automatically apply to any Javascript fetching you do