# How to stop caching pages that consume local json file in next js static generation?

Tags: reactjs, .htaccess, next.js, cpanel

I've deployed my next js app as static into my cpanel traditional hosting.
So some pages consume local json file that I fetch using getStaticProps, even using "revalidate" option.
When I edit the json file, the page does not update without clearing the website cache manually from google chrome. I've edited the .htaccess to not cache js,html,htm files and still same.

Answer (score 1):

At your fetch add a [Cache Buster](https://www.keycdn.com/support/what-is-cache-busting).

Checkout this answer:

[Cache busting via params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692665/cache-busting-via-params)