# Force browser to clear cache after deployment while deployment html and css changes

Tags: css, asp.net-core, caching, browser-cache, nopcommerce

Whenever we deploy Html and CSS changes. and those are not reflecting to end customer without full refresh (ctrl + f5) or clear history of there browser.

Anyone is facing such kind of issue?

What is the solution for this? does any code available that we put after deployment in order to load content from server instead browser cache and remove after some days.

we already tried this and no luck

```
<meta http-equiv=“Pragma” content=”no-cache”>
<meta http-equiv=“Expires” content=”-1″>
<meta http-equiv=“CACHE-CONTROL” content=”NO-CACHE”>
```

Comment: Just use *cache busting*, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692665/cache-busting-via-params