# Delete cache of specific XHR call

Tags: javascript, http, web, browser-cache, http-caching

I have a `XMLHttpRequest` that does a GET request:

```
const xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open("GET", "myapi/getThing", true)
```

Normally, the response stays the same so the server instructs to cache it with a HTTP response header:

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=604800, immutable
```

However, now I perform an action that I know for a fact will change the response, and so I call a `XMLHttpRequest` again, but the result won't change because of caching.

**How do I make it so the next XHR call of this resource won't use the browser cache?**

I have tried setting the `Cache-Control` to `no-cache` on the request:

```
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0")
```

But the browser still uses the cache.

**The goal is to explicitly NOT change the caching policy the server sets for performance reasons, so no validation and such. This should purely be the client wanting a 'fresh resource' on demand.**

Comment: a possible solution is to send any query param (even if it does nothing) to bust the cache. `myapi/getThing?a=1` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692665/cache-busting-via-params

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work for the next time `myapi/getThing` is called.

Comment: You can write code to generate a random string or number in place of `1` right before the request.

Comment: Looks like you misunderstood what I meant. I meant that when the page is reloaded, `myapi/getThing` is called again normally, and suddenly this 'deleted' cache 'comes back'.

Comment: Using `Cache-Control: no-cache` on the request is the way to do this, not sure why it isn't working for you. Try it in more than one browser.

Answer (score 1):

An effective solution:
[Cache busting via params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692665/cache-busting-via-params)
Assuming the server supports adding a useless parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I think both options could work, with cache busting as @Fudge Fudge suggested being the most frequently deployed one, something like:

`xhtp.open("YOUR_METHOD","your_url?" + (Math.random() * 1e16).toString(16))`

or you can use `Date.now()` etc., its up to you, sufficiently random number to guarantee uniqueness is enough.

The other way, would be to:

```
xhtp.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
xhtp.setRequestHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
xhtp.setRequestHeader("Expires","0");
```

sometimes old headers like `Expires` etc. can get the job done.