# How can I use css file versioning?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with css file versioning. When I`m using a file name "general.css" it`s work fine but if I change the file name on "general.css?v1.1" it`s not working. I can`t find this file as normal css file, for example in url address or page sources.

I`m expecting that, the css file will work with file name "general.css?v1.1".

Comment: Are you able to post your code that's calling the css?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/general.css?v1.1">

Comment: See [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692665/cache-busting-via-params) about cache busting with query string.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that adding the query string `?v=[number]` makes for a valid file name, which would explain why your HTML isn't registering it. You have to rely on other methods to get the site to register a version. This topic seems closely related to WordPress development and cache issues, and with that, you are able to pass a version number to the `wp_enqueue_style()` function. This will control your version number.

See https://youtu.be/1WJqINEp6qI