# How do I determine the version number of a minified JS file?

Tags: javascript, bundling-and-minification

How do I determine the version number of a minified JS file?  I'm using Visual Studio 2022 and the Bundler & Minifier VS Extension.  I'm referencing the file in my view by version number, so I'd like a way to determine the current version number of the min.js file.

The file is being consumed in the project using a version number like so:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/thing/ourthing.min.js?v=1.8"></script>
```

I don't see anything in the minified text to indicate what it might be.  I tried just incrementing it to the next version number, but it didn't include my change.

Copilot suggested the following grep command on the minified file, but it didn't find anything:
grep -o 'v[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+' file.min.js

Comment: Using what minification tool(s)?

Comment: Depends on the script and what minified it. There might not be any version information associated with the minified file at all.

Comment: @tadman I'm using the Bundler and Minifier extension in Visual Studio.

Comment: Depends if the tool does any versioning.... my guess it does nothing like that

Comment: That `?v=1.8` thing is largely cosmetic unless the server acts on it, which it usually won't for a static asset.

Comment: @tadman `/asset?v=1.7` is a different static asset to `/asset?v=1.8` as far as any browser is concerned

Comment: @andrew Absolutely, but server-side it will dish out the same asset file unless specially configured. To implement versioned assets you need both client and server to be on the same page.

Comment: @tadman what's the server-side element for Bundler & Minifier?

Comment: Many of the minifier/bundler solutions I've used generate an asset pack with a hash identifier, which is then used on the client side. It's `/asset-af0934...31.js` for example, where that hash is based on the content. The `?v=18` part is often ignored by static serving rules and just serves the same file regardless of what you put in there. It's just a *cache busting* trick for clients, not a versioning solution for the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You all were correct.  There isn't a generated "version number" for my change.  We just increment the version number so that the browser will request a new copy.  It's working now after clearing my browser cache.

Answer (score 1):

The version number at the end there doesn't actually change the content, it's there for [cache busting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692665/cache-busting-via-params) purposes.

You need to make sure the minification process has run again after you made changes to the file.

Also, note that copilot's grep command is wrong for your version number. Observe that the pattern `grep -o 'v[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+' file.min.js` contains **three** numeric groups (separated by two periods), but your version number only has two numbers (separated by a single period). Also, the version number in the search must be prefixed with the letter `v` before the first digit, but yours is not. This search would find a version number like `v1.2.3`, but not your `1.8`.

Comment: Ah good point.  I'll try revising that.

Comment: It still didn't find anything when I removed the v and looked for only 2 numbers.