# The server is not updating JS and CSS files on the domain, but PHP files are being updated

Tags: javascript, php, sass, server

I'm facing an issue where I've updated my code files on the server. The PHP files and SQL database reflect the changes, but the JS and CSS files seem to persist with the old versions. I've checked the Apache log, and there are no reported errors. The server team mentioned that updates should occur automatically, and no additional steps are required.

I've tried clearing the local storage cache in multiple browsers, and I also identified something resembling local storage on the server side, which I cleared. Despite these efforts, the client-side version of the website still shows the old JS and CSS files.

Any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: You cleared your browser cache?

Comment: Does the same happen in an incognito/private window?

Comment: Yes, incognito, multiple browsers, clearing cache local storage cookies...

Comment: that's not a solution.. but just as a quick attempt (cache busting), try referring to any given asset (inside your html) adding something like `resource.js?v=2` [here for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692665/cache-busting-via-params)

Comment: What HTTPResponseHeaders are sent with your CSS/JS files, you likely have a `Cache-Control` header that specifies an expires/age that is telling end user browsers to cache those files. In local development you likely don't want this, but in production you do. Be sure to change the URL to the CSS/JS files if you need to deploy updates to them.

Comment: Are you doing some sort of linking between a public resource folder and sources or a is a build step missing?

Comment: Thank you everyone. WOW. Especially thank you Marshall Davis. I cannot believe I forgot to build. I built for production, uploaded again and got it. WOW.