# Strange jQuery issue

Tags: jquery

I have inserted this script in a webpage with 50 small images ( from 16x16px to 50x50px ):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('img').css('opacity', '0.0').load(function(){
    $(this).animate({'opacity': '1.0'});
});         
});
</script>
```

The problem is that not every images are loaded and some doesn't appears.

Why ?

Comment: what is `.load(` ? are you trying to make ajax call ?

Comment: `.load(function)` attaches an `onload` event handler; method name is shared with the ajax-ey `.load(url)`.

Comment: can you provide us html sample?

Comment: The html is very simple ( with 50 img tags ) and without jquery it work perfectly.

Comment: Could be due to a few reasons, this might be relevant to you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5624901/551093

Comment: @RoyiNamir http://api.jquery.com/load/ (`Note: The event handling suite also has a method named .load(). jQuery determines which method to fire based on the set of arguments passed to it.`)

Comment: @lanzz thanks. if you google _jQuery Load_  - you get only to the ajax ver....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are chances that some images are being loaded from cache. And if the image is loaded from cach then `load` event would fire before `dom ready` event. One way to do this would be

```
$('img').css('opacity', '0.0').one('load',function(){
    $(this).animate({'opacity': '1.0'});
}).each(function() {
   if(this.complete) $(this).load();
});
```

This will loop through the images and check if they has been loaded from cache, if so then it will fire load event for those images.

And I am using [$.one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to run the event handler only one time as we dont need it to be executed more than one time.

**UPDATE:**

`if(this.complete)` will check if the image is already loaded(in case of cached they are) and if they are then it will fire `load` event for those immediately.

And which are not loaded from cache, browser will fire `load` event for them after they are loaded.

So the above code will cover all images, cached or not.

Comment: and if I want to do the animation for every images ( cached and not ), how can I do ?

Comment: This will do the animation for all images cached or not. :)

Comment: I have tested it and now all images are loaded but the animation works only on the uncached images :(

Comment: Can you share the url, so I can check?

Answer (score 4):

Some images might already be loaded when you set their opacity to 0, thus their `onload` handler has already run and you don't get the chance to make them visible again.

Comment: So, what it the best way to do that animation ? Thanks

Comment: Do not render the images directly in the HTML. Create the image instances with jQuery and attach the `onload` handler before you set their `src` attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Set the default `opacity` value within CSS style, not via javascript. After that, use `animate`.

```
<style>
     img { opacity:0 }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').load(function(){
        $(this).animate({'opacity': '1.0'});
    });         
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use Preload Images javascript code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (document.images) {
    img1 = new Image();
    img1.src = "image.jpg";
    img2 = new Image();
    img2.src = "image2.jpg";
}
</script>
```

and now all images preload into client machine and visible always....

OR

Flexible Array

```
function preload(images) {
    if (document.images) {
        var i = 0;
        var imageArray = new Array();
        imageArray = images.split(',');
        var imageObj = new Image();
        for(i=0; i<=imageArray.length-1; i++) {
            //document.write('<img src="' + imageArray[i] + '" />');// Write to page (uncomment to check images)
            imageObj.src=images[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is messy and repetitive. The OP says they have ~50 images. That's a lot of JavaScript, as well as the fact your code sample doesn't even append the image to the document.

Comment: OK in that case you can use array code : function preload(images) {
    if (document.images) {
        var i = 0;
        var imageArray = new Array();
        imageArray = images.split(',');
        var imageObj = new Image();
        for(i=0; i<=imageArray.length-1; i++) {
            //document.write('<img src="' + imageArray[i] + '" />');// Write to page (uncomment to check images)
            imageObj.src=images[i];
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

you can better set the opacity for images in css like

```
img {
opacity:0
}
```

and then use your code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('img').load(function(){
    $(this).animate({'opacity': '1.0'});
});         
});
</script>
```