# Showing images after they are loaded

Tags: jquery, css

I am searching for solution to my idea of showing images on website after they are loaded. When they are not loaded I want to hide them but leave a free space in the places they should be placed.

I need to show up images when they are loaded, because now they are loading in bad-looking way.

I tried with something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').css('opacity' , '0');
});

$('img').load(function(){
    $(this).css('opacity', '1');
});
```

Css provides animation of opacity by:

```
img{
   transitions: all 2s;
}
```

I was searching for other solutions but I did't find nothing interesting, thanks for all for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by 'bad-looking way'? Can you provide some screenshot?

Comment: I have about 20 images and they are loading so long each of them in different time that is 'bad' for me. I would like to see smooth appearing image after it is completely loaded. Now images are loading 'row by row' what is similar to printing an image.

Comment: `transition` not `transitions`. Also, if you are using an up to date version of jQuery it should be `$('img').on('load', function(){ ... })`

Answer (score 0):

First with CSS set opacity to 0, then with jquery set opacity to 1 or use jquery show or fadeIn.

styles.css

```
  img{
      opacity: 0;
  }
```

scripts.js

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
      $('img').css('opacity' , '1');
      // $('img').show("slow");
      // $('img').fadeIn("slow");
  });
```

https://api.jquery.com/show
https://api.jquery.com/fadein

Comment: doc.ready can fire before the images have loaded. OPs approach of using the loaded event of the images is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it should be `transition` and not `transitions`.

If you want the images to be hidden when the page loads, don't wait for the document.ready event to set the opacity to zero. Set this in your CSS.

If you are using a version of jQuery greater than 3 (which you should be), then you need to use `.on()` to bind your loaded event handler.

```js
$('img').on('load', function(){
    $(this).css('opacity', '1');
});
```

```css
img {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="https://placehold.it/1000x1000">
```

Comment: I did it just like you suggested me, but there is some problem. When I come to website first time (or when I force Google Chrome to reload files by Ctrl+Shift+R) images beautifully show on the page, but when I come to this website once more (or whe I use F5 to refresh) images stay transparent (code to show them is not started). I modified code like this:

`$('img').on('load', function(){
  $(this).css('opacity', '1');
  console.log('working!');
});`

And firs time logs are shown in console, next time there are no logs until I reload by force (Ctrl+Shift+R)

Comment: That will be due to the images being loaded from cache. Some solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624733/jquery-load-not-firing-on-images-probably-caching and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279135/jquery-fadein-images-after-dom-has-loaded-works-sometimes